# Find Numeric Values in Ruby and then Convert them to Strings

Tags: ruby, regex

I have files that have a bunch of lines containing text and numbers. The text in each file stays the same, but the numbers change. (This is running data, so the lines are things like "- Active Duration 28:19, - Total distance 3.66mi.", etc.)

What I want to do is locate the individual numbers in these lines, then create my own output, such as: "Ran #{distance} in #{time}"

I'm able to locate these numbers in the lines using regular expressions, but I cannot figure out how to then take those values and make them into their own strings. I'm not even sure regex is the right approach. I've been running things like this:

```
if line =~/\d*\.\d*/
found completed = true
```

But then I'm not sure what comes next.

I hope I'm being clear—and thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: can you post an example string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex in the element reference to get the number data. For example:

```
2.0.0-p0 :010 > distance = line[/\d*\.\d*/]
=> "3.66" 
2.0.0-p0 :011 > time = line[/\d*:\d*/]
 => "28:19" 
2.0.0-p0 :012 > puts "Ran #{distance} in #{time}"
Ran 3.66 in 28:19
 => nil
```

Comment: That looks really promising. Does it require anything? Right now I'm getting 'undefined local variable or method `line' for main:Object (NameError)'

Comment: Got it. Elegant and effective. Thanks!

Comment: I'd prefer `line[/\d+\.\d*/]`, `line[/\d+:\d+/]` in scanning the only occurrence of a pattern.

Comment: I like Arie's addition, that really smoothes things out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that:

```
rawlines = <<EOF
- Active Duration 28:19, - Total distance 3.66mi.
- Active Duration 25:12, - Total distance 3.66mi.
- Active Duration 24:10, - Total distance 3.66mi.
- Active Duration 28:21, - Total distance 3.66mi.
- Active Duration 27:19, - Total distance 3.66mi.
EOF

rawlines.scan(/Active Duration (\d++:\d++), - Total distance (\d++(?>\.\d++)?)/) do |dur, dist|
  puts "Ran #{dist} in #{dur}\n"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer to show iteration over file.**
I put the results into a hash so that key-value pairs could be utilised for the manipulation of the data. New keys could be added for the unit of measurement, etc.

**runData_20130620.txt**
-Active Duration 09.87, -Total Distance 100.0m
-Active Duration 15:19, -Total Distance 4.98km
-Active Duration 03:00, -Total Distance 1.0mile
-Active Duration 21:14, -Total Distance 3.68, -Sweat Produced 5.99Gallons
-Active Duration 22:31, -Total Distance 3.65mi

**Code**

```
File.foreach("runData_20130620.txt") do |line|

    # Create hash, parsing string with regex pattern
    runData = Hash[*line.scan(/([^, \-]\D*) (\d*[.:]\d*)/).to_a.flatten]

    # This will convert the string keys to symbols, replacing white-space with 
    # underscores and downcasing

    runData = Hash[runData.map { |k,v|
                        [k.gsub(/\s+/, "_").downcase.to_sym, v] }] 

    # display results
    #runData.each { |k,v| puts "#{k} ** #{v}" }

    # display using hash symbol access...
    puts "\nRan a distance of #{ runData[:total_distance]} in
                                               runData[:active_duration]} "
    puts "Man, I am unfit!" if runData[:sweat_produced]
end
```

**Results**

> Ran a distance of 100.0 in 09.87
>
> Ran a distance of 4.98 in 15:19
>
> Ran a distance of 1.0 in 03:00
>
> Ran a distance of 3.68 in 21:14
>       Man, I am unfit!
>
> Ran a distance of 3.65 in 22:31

Comment: You would need to modify the regex patterns - I tidied the data slightly first

Comment: Interesting—looks great! But how could I set this up as a script to read lines in a file? For example, "myData" is always changing, and I don't want to have to input it all by hand.

Comment: That shouldn't be too difficult using regular constructs. Does your file have a specified format i.e. is every line in the file the same structure? @craigeley

Comment: Each file contains lines such as: 
-   Active Duration 28:19
-   Total Distance 3.66 mi.

etc. etc.

Comment: There's always more than one way to skin a cat. Thanks!